# What does it mean these symbols?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, word-usage

[image]

Levi is trying to clean the room with the vacuum cleaner

Answer (score 3):

I believe "tch" represents a sound this character is making by pressing his tongue against the roof of his mouth and expelling a small amount of air; this conveys impatience, annoyance, or irritation. Likewise, the イライラ in the background shows that he is feeling annoyed.